# What is this operation in C?

Tags: c, binary, termcap

I start working with the termcaps and i saw this kind of operation.

`term.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON);`

I know `&=` is a `binary AND`, and i am not very confortable with it.

Why didn't simply use `=` or make a `#define`, and what the `&= ~` do ?

Comment: Why people unvote ??

Comment: Maybe because you will find the answer by just googling for "c operators" or in any C book, tutorial, etc.?

Comment: i did ! i look, i found few thing ... but i didn't understand why all of this have to do with termcaps !

Comment: Specifically, nothing.  It has to do with boolean algebra, ie. the way computers work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `ICANON` is a bit-mask, i.e. an integer with bits set to represent some feature, that statement will make sure those bits are *not* set in `c_lflag`.

This is often called "masking off" those bits.

The operation is a bitwise AND with the bitwise inverse (`~` is bitwise inverse).

So, if the value of `c_lflag` is 3 (binary 11<sub>2</sub>) before the operation, and `ICANON` has the value 2 (binary 10<sub>2</sub>), it will become 1 since it's bitwise-AND:ed with the value `~2` which has all bits set except bit number 1 (binary ...11101<sub>2</sub>).

It could also be written more verbosely as

```
term.c_lflag = term.c_lflag & ~ICANON;
```

The parentheses around `ICANON` should not be needed.

Answer (score 1):

Your line remove the bit(s) of `ICANON` from `term.c_lflag`:

Assuming terms ares 4 bits long, if the value of `ICANON` is 4 (0100b), then the value of `~ICANON` is 11 (1011b), and so:

```
    term.c_lflag  1 1 1 0
AND      ~ICANON  1 0 1 1
    ---------------------
                  1 0 1 0
```

==> 1010b, 10 in decimal

Answer (score 0):

```
term.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON);
```

is equal to

```
term.c_lflag = term.c_lflag & ~(ICANON);
```

& and ~ operators are two distinct operators. ~ is NOT operator in which it converts each bit with its inverse. & operator is bitwise AND operator in which it compares operands bit by bit.

Comment: It is not equal. There are subtle differences when evaluationg the lvalue.